Connect to SQL database using windows authentication
I have a SQL database on my computer that I am trying to connect to using python.
For starters, when I connected to the database with SQL Server Management Studio, I used the option connect with windows authentication. Now I am trying to connect to it the same way with python. Here is the code I have
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost; \
                      Database=fatigue_life_test_db;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

cnxn.close()

The second line is throwing the following error:
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (5); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

I also tried replacing the localhost with the name of the server (MSSQLSERVER) but it still gives the same error. I am quite new to SQL databases so there is probably something obvious that I'm missing here. I couldn't find a way to solve this issue even with an extensive googles search.

You can resolve this issue by following point:

Verify SQL Server Instance name: localhost or local
Check SQL Server service is running or not.
Make sure TCP/IP protocol is enabled. if not you can do via SQL server confiiguration manager.
Check windows firewall settings are not blocking your SQL Server instance.
Write this code and check again:


import pyodbc

try:
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'Driver={SQL Server};'
        r'Server=localhost,1433;'  # Assuming the default port 1433
        r'Database=fatigue_life_test_db;'
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    print("Connection established.")
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    print("Error in connection:", e)
finally:
    if 'cnxn' in locals() and cnxn:
        cnxn.close()



Than you this fixed my issue

I believe that your connection string is missing username and password. Try like this:
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost;Database=fatigue_life_test_db;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID={USERNAME};PWD={PASSWORD}')

You can get more info in the link below (see item #5):

Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc

